# How to export my Hybris website?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I've read the hybris wiki but I wasn't able to find any related information...I have made a website in one hybris platform on localhost, and now I need to get all the content, products, pages, etc and import it in another platform. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can export your data by writing Export Script.

**Creating Headers for Export**

- Log into the hybris Management Console.
- Navigate to System > Tools > Script Generator.
- In the Wizard: Script Generator, click on the Advanced Settings tab.
- Clear the Document ID check box.
- Switch back to the Script tab.
- Select [y] hybris MigrationScriptModifier from the Script modifier drop-down menu.
- Click the Generate button.
- The Script Generator writes the headers for all types in the hybris Commerce Suite into the Script field.
- Copy and paste the list of headers into a text editor.
- Remove the headers for the types you do not want to export.

Here are the list of some examples ->

- [Export CMS Content](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Export+CMS+Content+-+Tutorial)
- [Users and Addresses](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Export+Users+and+Addresses+-+Tutorial)
- [Catalog Version Content](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Export+the+Content+of+a+Catalog+Version+-+Tutorial)
- [Classification System](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Export+the+Content+of+a+Classification+System+-+Tutorial)

For More Information on How to run Export in different ways, Follow this link [Impex - User Guide](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+-+User+Guide#ImpEx-UserGuide-Export)

Answer (score 2):

### Quick and dirty db dump:

If you're not worried about overwriting existing data on the other platform, you could simply copy the database over. More than likely you will also need to copy the `hybris/data` folder, or you'll have missing media references. If you're using MySQL you can use the `mysqldump` utility. This is the quick easy way if you just need to stand up a UAT environment, for example.

### Impex export

The better way would be by creating impex scripts that will export all the items needed. On the hybris wiki, search for "Data Exporter", which is a page containing a link to an HMC extension called `advancedexport`. It will allow you to set up your export more easily.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply, I tried with data exporter, but when i reach the step to upload the sampleexport.csv there is an error: 11.03.2014 16:47:37: ERROR: line 1 at main script: unknown type 'AdvancedTypeExportConfiguration' in header 'INSERT_UPDATE AdvancedTypeExportConfiguration' (the error log is longer, but I can't paste it all)
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: It cannot find the composed type `AdvancedTypeExportConfiguration`. Did you run a system update after installing the extension?

Comment: Yes, once I installed the extension I went to platform -> update, but an error occurs: Error creating essential data for advancedexport. See console output. (the error in the console is like the one that can't find advancedTypeExportConfig'. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios :

1 - You have made all the website configuration by impex files and therefore you will just need to initialise your system on the new platform

---

2 - You have done all the website configuration manually

- If you are running the exact same Hybris version and code, then exporting / importing the data is possible
- If you are not running exactly the same platform, then it becomes tricky, you could either use import export functionality ([good examples here](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/How+To+Export+CMS+Content+-+Tutorial)) or try to generate Jinja templates for each item type ([example here](http://blog.hybhub.com/hybris-generate-impex-with-python-and-jinja.html))

Answer (score 0):

Another good option for you here will be to use the **Hybris-to-Hybris Synchronization** which will allow you to transfer all your data by taking advantage of Data Hub. This is a very good solution in cases where you want to keep a good performance in the origin system, or where you are dealing with different version of hybris. See more information on this [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8c8fb1468669101485da9c4d292cb103.html).